# Computation of conditional expectation

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, monte-carlo, conditional-expectation, density-estimation

Suppose that we have a random vector $X \in \Bbb R^n$ and a random variable $Y \in \Bbb R$, and that the joint density $f(x, y)$ is known. For a given $x \in \Bbb R^n$, what is the most efficient way in the statistics community to compute (or approximate) $E[Y| X = x]$?

Comment: "Most efficient" necessarily depends on the details of $f.$  Please edit your post to supply them.

Comment: @whuber There are no additional details on $f$, just that it can be an arbitrary continuous density for which you have the formula. I guess I am looking for well established methods for computing the conditional expectation.

Comment: See also comments in [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549686/general-and-specific-ways-to-compute-the-conditional-expectation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549686/general-and-specific-ways-to-compute-the-conditional-expectation).

Comment: That's too vague to be suitable here on CV, John; but if you have a specific problem then we could probably address it.  The thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531705 already deals with the basic concepts and formulas.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by "efficient" and "compute". Like what is wrong with $\int y \frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)} dy$?

Comment: @YashaswiMohanty I mean algorithms that the computer can follow, not pen and paper. I was thinking on Montecarlo related techniques specifically, but didn't want to mention it just in case there was something else I was not aware of. What is wrong with the formula is that you won't be able to integrate most of the time given a general $f$. I hope this makes it clearer.